# How do you say, ‘I wiped down the table.’ in Esperanto?

Tags: translation

My guess is, ‘Mi priviŝis la tablon.’

I mean in the sense of cleaning (as opposed to drying), but I am aiming, as does the English, at something more specific than, say, merely removing the dirty dishes, and less specific than, say, scrubbing out a stain.

Comment: With `viŝis` one can add an adverb or even: `Mi viŝis la tablon pura.` Maybe the sence is `tute` or `la tutan tablon`.

Answer (score 3):

I would just say:

> Mi viŝis la tablon.

The definition in PIV is:

> Purigi objekton, frotante ĝin per io, kio forigas polvon, malsekecon ks

That seems to match what I would understand by “wipe down the table”. I don’t understand what the *pri* in *priviŝi* adds to the word.

I think Karlomania’s suggestions are good too, but I wonder if you asked someone to “purigi la tablon” they might not think that necessarily involves getting out a cloth and wiping it.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "wiped down" in the sense of cleaning, you could say:

> Mi purigis la tablon.

If you mean "wiped down" in the sense of drying, you could say:

> Mi sekigis la tablon.